# C# properties hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to build a properties hierarchy for the TreeDescription type, so it will be possible to have an access to variables this way:

```
TreeDescription tree;
tree.coordinates.latitude = someDouble;
```

This works, but I'm not sure that it's the right way:

```
public class Coordinates
    {
        public double latitude;
        public double longitude;
        public Coordinates (double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }
    }

public class TreeDescription
{
    public Coordinates coordinates;

    public TreeDescription (Coordinates coordinates)
    {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    } 
}
```

Please, help!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code and can't even tell what the question is.

Comment: Welcome to the SO, I think your question is about a confirmation of your design, something like *Code Review*. if yes use [Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) - @Programmer Please be nice to new SO user ;).